# Search nested arrays in MongoDB documents

Tags: codeigniter, mongodb

I am developing an web app using Codeigniter and MongoDB. Users can save their favorites sounds in as "bookmarks". Each user get one document and then each sound is appended to an array in that document called sounds. Each sound got a set of tags that is also saved to the bookmark. How can I search a users bookmarks in their bookmark document? I want them to be able to search by tags (from the tag array).

This is my MongoDB document:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("4f15846a112bf6b725000000"),
    "owner": {
        "user_id": ObjectId("4f147e1709ab662061000000"),
        "session_id": "3424e3155a01e78c50a8498f78cc51d9"
    },
    "sound_files": [
        {
            "sound_id": ObjectId("4f1480ff09ab661a61000001"),
            "sound_url": "http://s3.amazonaws.com/4c/864ea8e92e6ec4408e248cc9brf008bd/18.wav",
            "sound_tags": [
                "sound",
                "new york",
                "cool"
            ]
        },
                {
            "sound_id": ObjectId("4f1480ff09ab661a61000001"),
            "sound_url": "http://s3.amazonaws.com/4c/864ea8e92e6ec4408e248cc9brf008bd/12.wav",
            "sound_tags": [
                "sound",
                "happy",
                "ocean"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "total": 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
db.col.find({'sound_files.sound_tags':"sound"})
```

EDIT: Not exactly what OP is looking for apparently. Waiting for a more precise description of the requirement.

Comment: That does not work. It only returns all items in the array even if the tags match only one item (tag array).

Comment: Yes, you always query for documents, not part of documents. You can't only return a specific element of the array. You didn't mention you wanted to in your question. If you want to query specific documents you'll have to put them in a top level collection.

Comment: Ok, but then I cannot get all items in an array that matches a specific query?

Comment: I need to search ONE document but not in the top level but by tags in the sounds_files array (using the sound_tags sub array).

Comment: Hi this is currently not possible - please vote on: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-828 / https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-142